# Can't access to a 'this' value in a function outside of constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn how to make an app like reactjs but not really using it. I'm following a tutorial but I have some challenges. I have a function called 'update' which fires when there is a change in the state. I have a 'menu' object that I import as a child. The thing is, I can't seem to access to this child object in the 'update' function. Please have a look at the following:

```
import onChange from 'on-change';
import Menu from './menu';

class App {
  constructor(){
    const state = {
      showMenu: false
    }
    this.state = onChange(state, this.update);
   
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    this.el.className = 'todo';
    // create an instance of the Menu
    this.menu = new Menu(this.state);

    // create a button to show or hide the menu
    this.toggle = document.createElement('button');
    this.toggle.innerText = 'show or hide the menu';

    this.el.appendChild(this.menu.el);
    this.el.appendChild(this.toggle);

    // change the showMenu property of our state object when clicked
    this.toggle.addEventListener('click', () => { this.state.showMenu = !this.state.showMenu; })
  }

  update(path, current, previous) {
    if(path === 'showMenu') {
> // show or hide menu depending on state
>       console.log (app.menu); // undefined
>       this.menu[current ? 'show' : 'hide'](); // not working cause 'this.menu' is undefined

    }
  }
}

const app = new App();

> console.log (app.menu); // here it console logs correctly the object

document.body.appendChild(app.el);
```

Can someone help me to figure out what is going on here? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `update()` method in your `App` class, you have to use `this.menu` instead of `app.menu`.

It should look like this:

```js
update(path, current, previous) {
    if(path === 'showMenu') {
        console.log (this.menu);
        this.menu[current ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    }
}
```

You can't use `app` within the `App` class because `app` is not defined there. You have to use the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#class_context) keyword to access the members in the class itself.

Hope this helps.